# Can Black create the second weakness?

Tags: analysis, endgame, bishop-endgame

I have played blitz game on *lichess* as Black and entered into drawn bishop endgame. My opponent tried to force the matters and lost in the end but at some point very interesting position arose, where White had only one permanent weakness.

I am interested to know if Black can win the following endgame by creating second weakness in White position, or simply breaking through with his king.

```
[Title "Black to move"]
[fen "8/p7/2bk1p2/2p3p1/5PP1/1B4K1/PP6/8 b - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After **1...Bd5**, Black can win at least a pawn. White cannot take on **d5** because that's a clearly won king endgame for Black- Black threatens to go **Kd4-Kd3-c2** and take the pawn on **b2**. If White tries to defend with **Ke2**, then **Ke4** from Black wins the **g-pawn** and the game.

Comment: I thought that pawn was on `a3`...